# How can I detect if the user navigates back from a screen?

Tags: android, visual-studio, performance, flutter, camera

Is there a way to detect if the user navigates back to the previous screen ? I have a page with camera initialized but when the user navigates back to the previous screen, the camera still works and it prints continuously

```
E/CameraCaptureSession(30921):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/CameraCaptureSession(30921):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
I/BufferQueueProducer(30921): [SurfaceTexture-0-30921-6](this:0x79c9057000,id:10,api:4,p:817,c:30921) queueBuffer: slot number is dropped, handle=0x7a8425fec0
```

Comment: it is used to go to another screen, but what if he presses the back button ?

Comment: I mean the back btn of the mobile not on the screen.

Comment: will it work the same ?

Comment: I think in your usecase overriding the `dispose` function of the `StatefulWidget` should be the approach and make sure that the module accessing the camera is cleaned up there

Comment: and How can I override the dispose function ?

Comment: cameraController.dispose ?

Comment: but there is already a function for the `cameraController.dispose`

Comment: didn't understand ur answer

Comment: about overriding dispose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap Your Scaffold with WillpopScope Widet and on will pop method will be activated when user clicks back ;
and If you want to detect what activates you've to ovveride dispose function

Comment: what is overriding dispose function ?